# Checkout for given revision with EGit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

Is it possible to download a project in the given revision state, like it is possible in Subversion, with Egit?

Answer (score 0):

With command-line git, you just do `git checkout a487ec83whatever`. I imagine EGit allows you to do a checkout and specify a specific revision, too.

Comment: I am finding that EGit functionality does not seem to correspond to command-line git functionality. 'git clone' does what you expect at the command line; I have not found any way to actually check out code using EGit. It appears to be an elaborate prank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In EGit, you can select a 'commit' or a 'tag' and then 'checkout'.